# len function not behaving as expected

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I'm building a function that's applying an additional tag to an aws instance based on a dict of tags that are passed in.

Expected behavior:
When more than one `TEST_CUSTOMER_ID` is are passed in, the function should return the following dictionary of tags:

```
{'foo': 'bar', 'Account': 'shared'}
```

The current behavior of the unit test function is only returning:

```
{'foo': 'bar', 'Account': [['test_customer_id1', 'test_customer_id2']]}
```

How can I fix this?

```
def get_acct_value(tags, customer_id, ceid):
    customer_id = [customer_id]
    
    if "Account" in tags:
        if tags["Account"] == customer_id:
            pass
        else:
            if len(customer_id) > 1:
                tags["Account"] = "shared"
            elif len(customer_id) == 1:
                tags["Account"] = customer_id
            else:
                raise exceptions.CustomerNotFoundError(f"No customer(s) found on {ceid}")
    else:
        if len(customer_id) > 1:
            tags["Account"] = "shared"
        elif len(customer_id) == 1:
            tags["Account"] = customer_id
        else:
            raise exceptions.CustomerNotFoundError(f"No customer(s) found on {ceid}")
    return tags
```

Unit test:

```
TAGS_NO_VALUE = {'foo': 'bar'}
TEST_CUSTOMER_ID_LIST = ["test_customer_id1", "test_customer_id2"]
TEST_CEID = "test_ceid"


def test_get_account_value_customer_list():
    response = tagging.get_acct_value(TAGS_NO_VALUE, TEST_CUSTOMER_ID_LIST, TEST_CEID)

    print(response)
```

## Other unit tests:

All three tests should return: {'Account': customer_id, 'foo': 'bar'}

```
TEST_CUSTOMER_ID = "test_customer_id"
TAGS_UNEXPECTED_VALUE = {'Account': '', 'foo': 'bar'} 
TAGS_EXPECTED_VALUE = {'Account': customer_id, 'foo': 'bar'} 

def test_get_acct_value_no_value():

    response = tagging.get_acct_value(TAGS_NO_VALUE, 
TEST_CUSTOMER_ID, TEST_CEID)

    print(response)


def test_get_acct_value_unexpected_value():

    response = tagging.get_acct_value(TAGS_UNEXPECTED_VALUE, TEST_CUSTOMER_ID, TEST_CEID)

    print(response)

def test_get_acct_value_expected_value():

    response = tagging.get_acct_value(TAGS_EXPECTED_VALUE, TEST_CUSTOMER_ID, TEST_CEID)

    print(response)
```

Comment: Why do you do: `customer_id = [customer_id]`? This only ensures that `customer_id` is a list of one item.

Comment: do you see how you've got a double-nested list there? that means that the outer list always contains only one item, regardless of how many items are in the inner list. len(outer_list) will always be 1.

Comment: Also, please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: removing the line mentioned in @quamrana 's comment should make it work as expected.

Comment: Your function is named `get_acct_value`, but you're testing `get_customer_account_value`.

Comment: @Esther: I don't think it will turn out to be as simple as that. I suspect the OP wants to test their function by passing a string of a customer id.

Comment: @quamrana then len() just returns number of chars in string, they would need to split on `,` or something to get a list first

Comment: @Esther: I meant that I suspect the OP wants their function to work if it is passed a single string containing a single customer id. I suspect that they are flip-flopping between two implementations, neither of which work.

Comment: @Esther, unfortunately, no :-( I tried that and it makes all test cases return "shared" value for the 'Account' tag.

Comment: Thank you. Forgot to change that when tweaking my code for stackoverflow lol @Barmar

Comment: @ambertaka: I see that you have posted just a single test. Your implementation has multiple `if` statements. You should really have at least as many tests as `if/else` clauses.

Comment: if you have only one item, is it in a list or just a string? if it's just a string, then `len` will return the length of the string

Comment: @quamrana That seems to be a side concern. If the one test is the one that is breaking, it's not in the scope of the question to be testing all the different paths. It's to figure out why the one test is breaking. Also, the many exit points of the function (different if/else branches) is a code smell, and a suggestion to refactor rather than simply add tests to test each exit. The proper path is to see if you can reduce the overall complexity of the function. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity

Comment: @NathanielFord: Well the OP does seem to be concerned about the other tests after trying esther's suggestion of deleting that single line.

Comment: @quamrana That is because because strings are valid inputs to `len()` - an expected issue with just removing that line. Put another way, removing that way doesn't fix this test, it just means that the error is different and this test is not properly testing for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're complicating yourself a great deal here. Let's break out this function differently:

```
def get_acct_value(tags, customer_ids, ceid):
    if len(customer_ids) == 0:
        raise exceptions.CustomerNotFoundError(f"No customer(s) found on {ceid}")
    tag = "shared" if len(customer_ids) > 1 else customer_ids[0]
    tags["Account"] = tag
    return tags
```

First, we know that if `customer_ids`, a list, is empty, we should raise an exception. *Do this first.* It's labelled 'bounds checking', and should be done before you try and process any data - that way you don't have to redo it on every branch of your code.

Secondly, we know that if the list is greater than one, we want our tag to be 'shared', meaning we have more than one customer id. Let's set a temporary variable with the name `tag` with 'shared' if we have a list greater than one. If the list is exactly one, we set it to the only available customer id.

Finally, we do the actual work - setting the account to the tag we have selected. Lines 4 and five could be combined to `tags["Account"] = "shared" if len(customer_ids) > 1 else customer_id[0]`.

Notably, your proximal issue is that the *type* of `customer_ids` being passed in *must be a list*. If it is a solitary value then you'll have an issue. You try to solve this by just casting it to a list, but if you want to accept either a list or a single value, you're better doing something like this:

```
customer_ids = customer_ids if isinstance(customer_ids, list) else [customer_ids]
```

This would result in something like:

```
def get_acct_value(tags, customer_ids, ceid):
    customer_ids = list() if customer_ids is None else customer_ids
    customer_ids = customer_ids if isinstance(customer_ids, list) else [customer_ids]
    print(f"type={type(customer_ids)} {customer_ids=}")
    if len(customer_ids) == 0:
        raise exceptions.CustomerNotFoundError(f"No customer(s) found on {ceid}")
    tags["Account"] = "shared" if len(customer_ids) > 1 else customer_ids[0]
    return tags
```

I've added an initial check for `customer_ids` to ensure it is not `None`, which would break your second check (to convert the value to a list if it is not one), since `list(None)` throws a `TypeError`.

Note that I would sooner name this function `update_account_tags()` or something like that, since it returns no value, just a dictionary of tags, which has an updated value for account.

Some guidance: if you find yourself doing a check, `if a in b`, where b is a dictionary, and you're planning to do something with `a`, the best thing to do is use the dictionary's function `get()`.

```
v = b.get(a, my_default)
```

`my_default` here can be whatever you want, and by default is `None`. So these are equivalent:

```
v = b.get(a)
v = b[a] if a in b else None
```

Secondly, if you find yourself in a situation where you're doing a check like this:

```
if tags["Account"] == customer_id:
    pass
else:
   tags["Account"] = customer_id
```

You might as well simply do this:

```
tags["Account"] = customer_id
```

The result is the same, and it's equally computationally complex. (If `customer_id` is replaced with a function like `get_customer_id()` this may not be entirely true, but as a first instinct it'll do you well.)

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining all of this! I really appreciate your help. I just tested the script, and it worked for this test, but made all other tests return "shared".

Comment: @ambertaka Hm. I did have a typo (pluralization, now fixed). Do you have a example input that caused a problem?

Comment: Just added the three affected unit tests.

Comment: In each of those tests you're passing the same `TEST_CUSTOMER_ID`, which is a list of two ids - so you would expect the `shared` value back? I think you need to change `TEST_CUSTOMER_ID` for each test, where one test has only a single element, one has no elements, etc.

Comment: The initial test in the post passes TEST_CUSTOMER_ID_LIST (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72551320/len-function-not-behaving-as-expected#:~:text=TEST_CUSTOMER_ID_LIST%20%3D%20%5B%22test_customer_id1%22%2C%20%22test_customer_id2%22%5D). TEST_CUSTOMER_ID is passed with a single value for the other 3 tests.

Comment: @ambertaka So it does! My bad - don't use `list(customer_ids)` use `[customer_ids]`. `list("abc")` converts to `["a","b","c"]` and not `["abc"]` which is why the function then fails to satisfy the test.

Comment: You are a live saver!! It works now! Thanks a ton! :'-)